# Kiel diri "flash card" en Esperanto? (instruhelpilo, ne elektronika disponaĵo por fotilo kpt.)

Tags: single-word-requests

Kiel diri [angla] "[flash card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashcard)" / [germana] "[Lernkartei](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernkartei)-Karte" en Esperanto?

El en.wikipedia:

> A **flashcard** or **flash card** is a card bearing information, as words or numbers, on either or both sides, used in classroom drills or in private study. One writes a question on a side and an answer overleaf. Flashcards can bear vocabulary, historical dates, formulae or any subject matter that can be learned via a question-and-answer format. Flashcards are widely used as a learning drill to aid memorization. They are often associated with spaced repetition, i.e. reviewed at expanding time intervals.
>
> Flashcards can be virtual, as those used by flashcard software, or physical.
>
> Flashcards are an application of the testing effect − the finding that long-term memory is increased when some of the learning period is devoted to retrieving the information through testing with proper feedback.

Do mi serĉas vorto aŭ esprimo, kiu signifas karto uzati por lerni per renversi ĝin.

(**Ne** vorto por [elektronika disponaĵo kiel "CompactFlash" kpt.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_card)!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unuamomente mi `flash card` pensigis min pri komputila memoro. [Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/index_en.php?vorto=flash) proponas

- **fulmomemora karto** por komputila memorkarto, tamen ankaŭ:
- **memoriga karto** por la instruhelpilo.

Comment: (En ĉi-tiu demando) mi ne interesas pri komputila memoro. "memoriga karto" sencas, sed ĉu ĝi estas uzata? Kelkfoje Komputeko proponas ne-uzatan aŭ maloft-uzatan esprimojn, mi kredas.

Comment: @das-g bona averto ke Komputeko malgraŭ ĝi montras fontojn, tamen ne tute objektiva ŝajnas (lau mia impreso). Ĉi-kaze tamen **memoriga karto** estas senproblema, eĉ se la pruvo de ofta uzado mankas.

Answer (score 2):

Laŭ Vikivortaro: *flashcard = **lernokarto**; **instrukarto***. Kvankam la difino de Komputeko (*memoriga karto*) ankaŭ bonas, ĝi tamen donas al mi la impreson, ke eble temas pri unuopa karto por memorigi pri specifa afero (ekz. *forĵeti la rubon, promenigi la hundon*, ktp). Kontraste, la vortoj *lernokarto* kaj *instrukarto* klare indikas, ke temas pri io, kion oni lernas aŭ studas. Sed tio estas nur mia persona impreso, kaj mi ne scias ĉu la vorto *memoriga karto* (aŭ la du aliaj) estas vaste uzata en la senco de *flashcard* en Esperantujo.

PS: eble ankaŭ bonas la vorto ***memorslipo*** (vidu  [Kiel diri “index card” / “Karteikarte” en Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/kiel-diri-index-card-karteikarte-en-esperanto))

Answer (score 1):

Mi proponas al vi "memorkarto" aŭ "returnebla memorkarto".

Comment: Ĉu ne "memorkarto" estas elektronika disponaĵo (angla [memory card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_card) / germana [Speicherkarte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speicherkarte))?

Comment: @das-g Ne estas problemo se tiu vorto povas signifi plurajn aferojn

Comment: Jes, sed ĉu tio vorto vere signifas plurajn (kaj tiel malsimilajn) aferojn?