# Kiel diri "index card" / "Karteikarte" en Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Antaŭ komputilajn datumbazojn, oni ofte uzis fizikajn indeksojn (angla: "index", germana: "[Kartei](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartei)") por enmemorigi kaj administri datumojn.

Kio estas la esprimo por la kartoj, el kiaj konsistas tia fizika indekso? (Angla: "[index card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_card)", germana "[Karteikarte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karteikarte)".)

[image: A hand-written American index card.]
bildo CC BY 2.0 [BuffaloLibrary](https://www.flickr.com/people/79756778@N00)

[image: An (otherwise yet empty) ruled index card]
bildo CC BY 3.0 [E.m.fields](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:E.m.fields)

Ĉu sama esprimo estus uzata, se tia karto ne estas parto de indekso? (Oni povas uzi tia karto(j)n ankaŭ kiel [memoriga karto(j)](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/5144/1576) (angla "Flash card(s)") (tiel eble ankaŭ parto de ia "indekso"?) aŭ por ludi la ludo [1000 Blank White Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1000_Blank_White_Cards) aŭ treeble por aliaj uzadoj.)

Comment: Btw., is "indekso" even the right term for these kinds of (physical) "index"?

Answer (score 1):

Laŭ PIV tia karto nomiĝas **slipo**:

> Kartona aŭ papera folieto, de formato taŭga por esti facile klasebla,
>   kaj servanta por ricevi skribajn notojn, kiujn oni povas aranĝi laŭ ia
>   ordo: *slipoj de biblioteko; la tuta vortaro estas ankoraŭ nur sur
>   slipoj*.

Laŭ PIV *card index* estas **sliparo** (aro da slipoj) kaj **slipujo** (meblo por slipoj). Vikivortaro ankaŭ donas la vorton **kartoteko**.

La frazoekzemploj kiujn mi trovis en Tekstaro pensigas min, ke *slipo* povas esti uzata eĉ se ĝi ne apartenas al iu sliparo. Jen ekzemplo el Tekstaro:

> Ĉar li timas, ke iu dume trinkos lian multekostan vinon, li lasas
>   slipon sur la tablo: “Mi kraĉis en la glason”.

Comment: Mi skribis _index card_, anstataŭ _card index_. Mi redaktis mian respondon. Dankon por la atentigo.

Comment: Ĉi tiu demando multe memorigas min pri via alia demando: [Kiel diri “flash card” en Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5142/kiel-diri-flash-card-en-esperanto-instruhelpilo-ne-elektronika-disponaĵo-po) Eble oni povas uzi _slipo_ tiusence: _Mi plibonigas mian Esperanton pere de memorslipoj (aŭ pere de memorsliparo)_.

Comment: Feel free to add another answer to https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/5142/1576, or to amend your existing one there. :-)

Answer (score 0):

La vorto "slipo" povas esti uzata kun adjektivo por precizigi la signifon. Ekzemple, en Vikipedia artikolo https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_La_Fontaine oni trovas la frazon "Ankaŭ la normigita **biblioteka slipo** (12,5 × 7,5 mm) estas ilia kreaĵo".